# How do I find a word in a Excel spreadsheet and read the row the word is in into a list using Python?

Tags: python-3.x

So I want to have the user input a name, then find the name's row and read it into a list.
(It is a .csv file)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post some code and what you've tried so we can help you get there. Btw, .xlsx files are also in a less-than-easy to read format, so I'd recommend exporting to csv.

Comment: There are [packages to access Excel data directly](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=excel&submit=search).